# Streaming Data over RF

Tags: rf

I have the need to monitor a remote facility using  8 x CCTV and an intrusion alarm. I would like to use a cloud based software to manage this system. This site has no 3G or 4G coverage however we have a good signal 2km away. Does anyone know if the kit exists so that I can transmit the data from our racks on site over RF and then link to the 4G system? Thanks

Comment: Of course that exists but not on the consumer level and also not as a DIY solution. An alternative would be to connect to the internet over a satellite connection.

Comment: If you can afford the solution, you can afford to pay someone to implement it.

Comment: The key question is if you have line-of-sight for a microwave link, or if you can lease an exiting wire or fiber or get permission to run your own.

Answer (score 2):

That is more a computer networking question than pure electronics. Have a look at [Ubuqiuti](https://www.ubnt.com/) equipment. They do both cameras and radio equipment, 2km range is easy if you have line of sight.